# Как кастомизировать QSlider определенным образом?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, qss, qslider

Главный контейнер моего приложения `self.box` содержит в себе **4** виджета:

1. Кнопка `play_btn`, которая начинает воспроизведение mp3-файла из словаря `self.dict`;
2. Кнопка `pause_btn`, которая останавливает воспроизведение mp3-файла;
3. Надпись `label`, которая показывает название воспроизводимого mp3-файла;
4. **Слайдер `self.qsl`**, который контролирует момент воспроизведения mp3-файла.

Визуальные характеристики `self.qsl` мне нужно изменить следующим образом:

1. Высота полосы слайдера равна `7px`.
2. Часть слайдера, которая обозначает уже воспроизведенную часть файла (на рисунке обозначена цифрой **3**) имеет цвет, отличающийся от цвета части слайдера, которая обозначает еще не воспроизведенную часть файла (на рисунке обозначена цифрой **2**). **Обе эти части имеют закругленные углы.**
3. Ползунок слайдера (на рисунке обозначен цифрой **1**) имеет форму круга диаметром 14px. Хотелось бы иметь возможность настроить его цвет.
4. Ползунок слайдера (на рисунке обозначен цифрой **1**) имеет обводку. Хотелось бы иметь возможность настроить щирину и цвет этой обводки.
5. Ползунок слайдера (на рисунке обозначен цифрой **1**) может просто представлять из себя картинку с вышеописанными характеристиками: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пожалуйста, скажите, как это сделать?

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui, QtMultimedia

class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.dict = {
            'C:/Users/User/Desktop/Player/music/13.Numb.mp3': []
        }
        self.song = ''

        self.player = QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer()
        self.player.stateChanged.connect(self.playerState)

        self.qsl = QtWidgets.QSlider(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, self)
        self.qsl.sliderMoved[int].connect(self.SetPlayPosition)
        self.qsl.sliderReleased.connect(self.slider_released)

        self.box = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)   

        for line, song in enumerate(self.dict):     
            play_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Play', clicked=lambda ch, song=song: self.play(song))

            pause_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Pause', clicked=self.pause, enabled=False)

            label = QtWidgets.QLabel(song)
            self.box.addWidget(play_btn, line, 0)
            self.box.addWidget(pause_btn, line, 1)
            self.box.addWidget(label, line, 2)

            self.dict[song].append(play_btn)
            self.dict[song].append(pause_btn)

        self.box.addWidget(self.qsl, 2, 0, 1, 3)

        self.Play_Pause = True
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer(self)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.PlayMode)
        self.timer.start(1000)

    def PlayMode(self):
        if self.Play_Pause==False:
            self.qsl.setMinimum(0)
            self.qsl.setMaximum(self.player.duration())
            self.qsl.setValue(self.qsl.value() + 1000)

    def slider_released(self):
        self.player.setPosition(self.qsl.value())

    def SetPlayPosition(self, val):
        pass

    def play(self, song):
        if self.player.isAudioAvailable() == False:
            self.player.setMedia(QtMultimedia.QMediaContent(QtCore.QUrl(song)))
            self.dict[song][1].setEnabled(True)
            self.song = song

        if self.song == song:
            pass
        else:
            self.player.setMedia(QtMultimedia.QMediaContent(QtCore.QUrl(song)))
            self.dict[self.song][1].setEnabled(False)
            self.dict[song][1].setEnabled(True)
            self.song = song

        self.player.play()
        self.Play_Pause=False

    def pause(self):
        self.player.pause()
        self.Play_Pause=True
  
    def playerState(self, state):
        if state == 0:
            self.Play_Pause=True
            self.qsl.setSliderPosition(0)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.setWindowTitle('MP3-player, PyQt5')
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: [QSS Examples: Customizing QSlider](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qslider)

Comment: Почему так происходит? XD https://skr.sh/v92k3aVkucn?a QSlider::groove:horizontal { border-radius: 10px; border: 5px solid rgb(52, 59, 72) ; height: 10px; } QSlider::handle:horizontal { background-color: rgb(224, 71, 89); border: 2px solid rgb(224, 71, 89); height: 10px; width: 13px; margin: -4px 0; border-radius: 8px ; padding: -4px 0px; } QSlider::add-page:horizontal { background: rgb(52, 59, 72); border-radius: 10px ; } QSlider::sub-page:horizontal { background:rgb(52, 59, 72); border-radius: 10px ; }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это может выглядеть примерно так:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui, QtMultimedia

class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.dict = {
            'D:/_Qt/EXE/Mp3/new_build/QThread_mp3/img/zvuki_prirody.mp3': []
        }
        self.song = ''

        self.player = QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer()
        self.player.stateChanged.connect(self.playerState)

        self.qsl = QtWidgets.QSlider(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, self)
        self.qsl.setMinimumHeight(30)                                         # +++
        
        self.qsl.sliderMoved[int].connect(self.SetPlayPosition)
        self.qsl.sliderReleased.connect(self.slider_released)

        self.box = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)   

        for line, song in enumerate(self.dict):     
            play_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Play', clicked=lambda ch, song=song: self.play(song))

            pause_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Pause', clicked=self.pause, enabled=False)

            label = QtWidgets.QLabel(song)
            self.box.addWidget(play_btn, line, 0)
            self.box.addWidget(pause_btn, line, 1)
            self.box.addWidget(label, line, 2)

            self.dict[song].append(play_btn)
            self.dict[song].append(pause_btn)

        self.box.addWidget(self.qsl, 2, 0, 1, 3)

        self.Play_Pause = True
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer(self)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.PlayMode)
        self.timer.start(1000)

    def PlayMode(self):
        if self.Play_Pause==False:
            self.qsl.setMinimum(0)
            self.qsl.setMaximum(self.player.duration())
            self.qsl.setValue(self.qsl.value() + 1000)

    def slider_released(self):
        self.player.setPosition(self.qsl.value())

    def SetPlayPosition(self, val):
        pass

    def play(self, song):
        if self.player.isAudioAvailable() == False:
            self.player.setMedia(QtMultimedia.QMediaContent(QtCore.QUrl(song)))
            self.dict[song][1].setEnabled(True)
            self.song = song

        if self.song == song:
            pass
        else:
            self.player.setMedia(QtMultimedia.QMediaContent(QtCore.QUrl(song)))
            self.dict[self.song][1].setEnabled(False)
            self.dict[song][1].setEnabled(True)
            self.song = song

        self.player.play()
        self.Play_Pause=False

    def pause(self):
        self.player.pause()
        self.Play_Pause=True
  
    def playerState(self, state):
        if state == 0:
            self.Play_Pause=True
            self.qsl.setSliderPosition(0)


QSS = """
QSlider::groove:horizontal {
    border-radius: 1px;       
    height: 7px;              
    margin: -1px 0;           
}
QSlider::handle:horizontal {
    background-color: rgb(85, 17, 255);
    border: 2px solid #ff0000;
    height: 14px;     
    width: 12px;
    margin: -4px 0;     
    border-radius: 7px  ;
    padding: -4px 0px;  
}
QSlider::add-page:horizontal {
    background: #1abc9c;
}
QSlider::sub-page:horizontal {
    background: darkgray;
}
"""

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    
    app.setStyleSheet(QSS)
    
    window = MyWindow()
    window.setWindowTitle('MP3-player, PyQt5')
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо! Единственная проблема - у полосы слайдера не закруглены углы. Я пытался задать `border-radius` в таблице стиля, но ничего не выходит:(

Comment: @MAXIM045  попробуйте вставить `border-radius: 2px;` в селекторы `QSlider::add-page:horizontal {` и `QSlider::sub-page:horizontal {`.

Comment: Огромное вам спасибо еще раз. Добавлял в эти селекторы `border-radius`, но ставил слишком большие значения, из-за чего углы наоборот становились прямыми. Я думал, логика скругления в таблицах работает немного иначе. Теперь все хорошо

Comment: @MAXIM045 дело в том, что  `margin:` и `padding:` также влияют на отрисовку. Попробуйте поиграть цифрами, чтобы понять зависимости.